# how can i create view controller in Xcode 13.2.1?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I just started to learn iOS development and I got a problem to add outlet variable. As I watched video about making project with Xcode, I found that there was an option to select interface like swiftui. But in Xcode 13.2.1 I couldn't find that option and after making project, there wasn't storyboard and view controller. as far as I know, when the project is just created, there must be several files like app delegate, scene delegate, storyboard, view controller in navigator.

plz let me know how to add view controller to navigator.
I can't find the area that label is needed to be dragged into.
To give further information I posted pictures together about it.
thank you!

[interface selection in project production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBBCn.jpg)

[no interface selection in project production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCWPS.png)

[file lists in navigator as usual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgcjL.jpg)

[file lists in navigator when I created the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBhCf.png)

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Your third picture shows a default view controller and a storyboard. In your first picture, click on SwiftUI and Storyboard is displayed as an option.

Comment: oh I added more picture to specify what I wanted to say. 1,3 are what people can when they create the new project. However in my case I can't see the same screen like them. 2,4 are what I could see when I created the first project. There were no selection options as swiftui.

Comment: I see. This is because you choose "Multiplatform" on the previous screen when you choose a template for your new project. Make sure that you choose "iOS" (or MacOS).